# How can I import public keys into armory?

Tags: armory

I have a wallet on my phone and second, Armory wallet on my computer.  How can I import the public keys from my phone into Armory so that Armory can watch the balance.  I don't want to import the private keys, just the public ones.

Comment: Isn't that what "watching-only wallets" are for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's currently not possible with Armory.

Here is [the issue for the feature request](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/issues/40). The main developer of Armory is currently preparing a big change to the whole backbone of the client. The new backbone should make this possible.

> etotheipi told me this will be possible with the new wallets format.
>
> ([comment on issue](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory/issues/40#issuecomment-12174660))